# load menu div into the Content div not in new tab

Tags: php, html, target

I am trying to update an old frames site. Header/Menu/Content format.
I am just starting to learn about divs.
I have created 3 divs Header/Menu/Content. Looks great.
I want to click an item in the Menu div, and load it into the Content div...
Here's my attempt

```
<body>
    <div id="header">HEADER TEXT</div>
    <div id="menu">LINKS
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1.htm" target="content"> Link 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link2.htm" target="content"> Link 2 </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link3.htm" target="content"> Link 3 </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
</body>
```

The links open in a new tab. What am I missing?
I have been researching and found reference to iframe. Is this what's needed?

now i have solved that.. using [This Link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/215340-open-href-into-a-div/)
but in that case i am not able to give the book mark.. how can i overcame this problem?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: your missing some javascript action, the easier path would be to use something like `jquery` and then use the `$('#content').load('link1.htm')` functionality

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change div's content without javascript. You might want to use jQuery - put the following script in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu a").click(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $("#" + $this.attr("target")).load($this.attr("href"));

            e.preventDefault();// to make browser not follow the link
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a php switch function but you have to have the switch inside of the target div and the links outside of that div (in that case it is a matter of positioning you links and the div properly.

You can also do it using $_GET and $_POST together (with a switch again is preferable IMO) It's a complicated thing to elaborate on here.

But and here's the thing sometimes it is something you can benefit from: such as if you are dealing with a whole host of templates/themes and those themes have in them jscript as versions of ajax and the like; these will conflict if you use different versions on the same webpage. So if you go to use your version of ajax to do the job and the template does not use the same version (which is very likely to happen) then using ajax or jquery will not work. If that is the case then you will have problems using ajax or jquery to do the job for you (there are various versions being used now and you cannot use 2 different versions on the same webpage in my experience.

Use ajax, jquery javascript is the better way because php is a server side scripting language and javascript (ajax, jquery) are client side scripting languages and are used to interact with the server from the client page: if this is done right then the server replies directly and that reply is caught by the javascript function parsed onto the same page at that instant during run-time that is stipulated in the script. If you want to learn about using $_POST and $_GET (they are predifined php functions, and can be used together) then do some research using google searches will do the trick. And also do some research on PHP switch functions.

this link uses $_GET and $_POST in a switch its a great inllustration:
http://www.intechgrity.com/using-php-get-and-post-simultaneously-via-single-html-form/#

I hope this helps you
G